# Storing important information for a company

Tags: security

I work in a web development company and they have all the passwords, host addresses, etc. vital information in a spreadsheet on a local machine in the intranet.

While secure from external attacks, I find it a little messy. There are many incomplete fields and sometimes even typos. What do you guys think would be other ways to store this information in an efficient yet secure way?

Comment: google "cmdb". That's essentially what you want.

Comment: The concept sounds good, but is there any open software solution I could take a look at, to understand it better?

Comment: request tracker and the asset tracker plugin

Comment: GLPI is probably the least-worst open-source CMDB. It's kind of a bear to set up, though.

Comment: "least worst" seems to the point. It's french-driven and as such only scarcely documented for non-french-speakers. You need to figure out a lot yourself by looking at the PHP code or messing around with the UI, where translations are not always matching the functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeepassX is Open Source and the database is fully encrypted. You can store other information other than just passwords in it. I put it on a dropbox account and then share that folder out with the others needing access. I don't think that will scale to hundreds but it works for 4 people just fine.

Comment: +1 A very similar product that works better cross-platform is Password Safe.

Answer (score 1):

A tool like Password Vault comes to mind - http://www.lavasoftware.com/passwordvault.html

Comment: I would like more than just passwords. Theres a whole bunch of data that needs also storing.

Comment: You can store text in Password Vault also. Not just passwords.

Comment: Does it allow to have information centralized, so that different people can access to it at the same time?

Comment: I am pretty sure it does or other tools like it. I provided a link to check out for it above, answers all of those questions...